# Are "has there ever been" questions always [history] questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Regarding questions for the [history](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag, are "has there ever been" questions always [history] questions?

Currently, most questions do not use the tag.

- Tagged [history]: 9 ([See the list](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22has+there+ever+been%22+%5Bhistory%5D+is%3Aq))
- Not tagged [history]: 33 ([See the list](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22has+there+ever+been%22+-%5Bhistory%5D+is%3Aq))

Searching for "ever been" and excluding "has there ever been",

- Tagged [history]: 4 ([See the list](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22ever+been%22+-%22has+there+ever+been%22+%5Bhistory%5D+is%3Aq))
- Not tagged [history]: 84 ([See the list](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22ever+been%22+-%22has+there+ever+been%22+-%5Bhistory%5D+is%3Aq))

The tag limit of 5, mentioned as a concern in [this question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5962/26455), applies here, as some questions without the [history] tag already have 5 tags.

---

Related: [Should we explicitly disallow “has X happened before” questions?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3543/26455)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it happens, not always. Posts sometimes ask supplementary questions. If the main or only question, ask "has there ever been" then yes. If asked in a supplementary question, then no.

For example, in [Would it be possible to implement a policy that forbids promotion of brands in media?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/10419/26455), the main question asks about a policy; but the supplementary question includes a "has there ever been" question.

A second example, in [Can vice president/security advisor or secretary of state be chosen from the opposite party?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/62697/26455), a supplementary contains the question.